# Controlling Orientation in 3D PGF Plots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

**Question**

Why does `x-axis` pointing right and `y-axis` pointing into the page appear to be the default? When I found the page in the following link, the answer coincidentally presented the axes exactly how they are used by default in the university where I teach first years. This was what I was trying to achieve when I got sidetracked by the bug.

My initial solution was to use `view/h=120` as an axis option which at least gave me x pointing out of the page and y on the right, but not horizontal.

Another solution I found is setting the x, y and z vectors. It took me ages to find this in the manual because these three letters are all over the place, I eventually concocted a search string that narrowed it down. Setting the vectors seems a bit fiddly though.

It doesn't look too bad, but it took some tweezing of numbers to find a reasonable result. Is there any advice on how best to achieve z axis vertically +ve up, y axis horizontally +ve right, x axis +ve out diagonally down to the left? Or, how best to do this in general whatever orientation you choose.

**Conclusion**

Currently, specifying all three vector directions and then tweezing their scaling so that the result looks relatively balanced is the best way to control 3D axis orientation. I'm really looking forward to Christian's proposed new feature which would leave us only having to specify the vector directions. That would be cool.

**MWE**

[image: MWE Output]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
%
\par\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    x={(-0.3cm,-0.3cm)}, y={(.5cm,0.0cm)}, z={(0cm,.1cm)},
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    xtick={-2,2}, ytick={-2,2},ztick={16,32},
    enlargelimits=true
    ]
\addplot3[surf, thick, color=green, domain=-4:4] {x^2+y^2};
%
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've just added in a conclusion now this has been satisfactorily resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your choice requires manually provided unit vectors as the `view` key generates no skewed axes. That means explicitly provided unit vectors are currently the best way to arrive at this particular view.

This remark is about the directions of the vectors. The following is about the (relative) sizes:

There is a feature in pgfplots in which you can provide `x=...,y=...,z=...` and `scale mode=scale uniformly` in order to respect the directions and relative lengths and rescale by means of a common factor.

Seems as if there *should* be support for `scale mode=stretch to fill` as well - in that case the fiddling would have been unnecessary: you could say `x={-0.3,-0.3}, y={1,0}, z={0,1}, scale mode=stretch to fill` and all would be well.

Unfortunately, that choice appears to be unsupported. I take that as a feature request / bug report for `pgfplots`; it will be available eventually (should be fairly simple as all required mechanisms are available).

---

*EDIT* 
As you showed interest in the feature, I experimented a bit with that feature and arrived at the following. My envisioned input for the feature would be

```
x={(-.307pt,-.307pt)}, y={(1pt,0.0pt)}, z={(0pt,1pt)},
scale mode=stretch to fill,
```

As result, `pgfplots` would be able to generate

[image]

*ATTENTION*: this is NO currently available feature.

Comment: (1) Does this mean that you think tweezing the vectors is the best way currently available? (2) That feature upgrade sounds cool, but isn't the idea of scaling the vectors to get some kind of visual balance? Their relative values is part of that balance, based on human obsrervation. How could a computer routine know how to calculate `x={(-0.3cm,-0.3cm)}, y={(.5cm,0.0cm)}, z={(0cm,.1cm)}` from `x={-0.3,-0.3}, y={1,0}, z={0,1}`? I came up with that particular ratio based on my own visual aesthetic, someone else would come up with something different? How do you code a decision like that?

Comment: See my edit: I would take the box defined by your input vectors and would compute scaling factors for all x and all y components of the 2d units. I would also respect the involved axis limits.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: What does the "view"-key do then? It appears in several answers related to my specific problem, that is creating an opened spherical shell at an angel upon a Cartesian axes, however save looking through the TikZ-PGF manual, it is difficult to ascertain what its purpose is. Some answers have "view/h" defined as 45 or 120.

Comment: You can find the precise definition of the key `/pgfplots/view` in the manual for `pgfplots` , Section "3D Axis Configuration", subsection "View Configuration". It also explains the difference between `view` and `view/h`. You can also click in any associated example (which will navigate you to the reference documentation).