# Change direction of axis, tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I want to get an axis system as shown in the figure.

I tried reversing an axis, but label axis is not placed in the right location. I can rename the rest of the axis, but it is so uncomfortable to draw all my figures changing coordinates.

Please help me.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.8,
        every axis/.append style={
            axis lines=center,
            xlabel style={anchor=south west},
            ylabel style={anchor=south west},
            zlabel style={anchor=south west},
            tick align=outside,
        },
    }


\begin{document}
    

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis} [
            xlabel={$x$},
            %ylabel={$z$},
            zlabel={$y$},
            y dir=reverse,
        ]
            \addplot3+ coordinates {(0,0,0) (4,0,0) (4,0,4) (0,0,4) (0,0,0)};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why use an old version of PGFPlots? I do not know if your issue has anything to do with the version, but step one must be to upgrade your system and use the newest version. `compat=1.17`.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Thanks, I change for $compat=1.17$. My problem persists.

Comment: You label your z-axis with "y" !! That is super confusing and not needed. If you want to change the direction of the axis, you can use `x=..., y=..., z=... ` like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139686/controlling-orientation-in-3d-pgf-plots

Comment: @hpekristiansen there is a citation to the $pgf$ manual. Do you know which page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the direction of the axis with `x=..., y=..., z=...`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [ 
            axis lines=center,
            x={(.5cm,-0.1cm)}, y={(0cm,0.5cm)}, z={(-0.3cm,-0.3cm)},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            zlabel={$z$},
            xmax=8, ymax=4, zmax=8,
            ticks=none,
            clip=false
        ]
            \addplot3+ coordinates {(0,0,0) (4,0,0) (4,0,4) (0,0,4) (0,0,0)};
            \addplot3+ coordinates {(0,2,0) (4,2,0) (4,2,4) (0,2,4) (0,2,0)};
            \node at (0,2,4)[above left] {$P(0,2,4)$};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with y-axis pointing up]

Comment: How do you calculate the values for x, y and z? I want to rotate the axis to show some parts of the graph.

Comment: When I change the values, the scales are different, no matter if d_I write $$scale mode=scale uniformly$$ or  $$axis equal$$.

Comment: Trial and error?

Comment: `x=..., y=..., z=...` gives the unit vectors. What do you mean by uniform scale in 3D (projected onto 2D)? I do not know what you mean by "rotate the axis to show some parts of the graph". Maybe a new question with a MWE an a sketch of the desired result?

Comment: `x={(.5cm,-0.1cm)}, y={(0cm,0.5cm)}, z={(-0.3cm,-0.3cm)}` is just some numbers picked to look like your picture.

Comment: Thanks, I posted a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `3dtools` from [here](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools)

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round, 
            3d/install view={phi=100,theta=70}]
            \path (1,0,0) coordinate (ez) (0,1,0) coordinate (ex)
            (0,0,1) coordinate (ey);
            \begin{scope}[x={(ex)},y={(ey)},z={(ez)}] 
                \draw[-stealth,thick] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[pos=1.05]{$x$};
                \draw[-stealth,thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,3.5,0) node[pos=1.05]{$y$};
                \draw[-stealth,thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,6.5) node[pos=1.15,thick]{$z$};
    \draw[thick] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0)-- (4,0,4)-- (0,0,4)-- (0,0,0)
 (0,2,0)-- (4,2,0)-- (4,2,4) --(0,2,4) --(0,2,0)    
    (0,0,4) -- (0,2,4) 
    (4,0,4) -- (4,2,4)
    (4,0,0) -- (4,2,0)  
    ;
    \node at (0,2,4)[above left] {$P(0,2,4)$};
            \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]